# $route.params With Vue Route and Vue 3 TypeError: Undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue3, vue-router

llevo varios días atascado con un problema que tengo con Vue Router, estoy inetntando hacer una aplicación similar a un videoclub a forma de "trastear". El problema principal es que no puedo acceder al valor de $this.route.params a la hora de crear una variable o hacer alguna prueba lógica con el, pero si puedo imprimirlo en la consola del navegador desde mis computer properties (mirar primera parte del código y 1era captura).

Siguiendo el tutorial de Vue Router de Vue Schools.IO, cree una computed property que me permita acceder al valor de la ruta, pero esto tampoco me sirvió (revisar segunda captura y segunda parte de código).

¿En que puedo estar fallando?, he probado y consultado varios foros pero no alcanzo a ver el problema. Gracias de antemano y un cordial saludo.

Este es mi código

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>"{{ getServices.slug }}"</h1>
    <div>
      <p>{{}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import servicios from "../../data.json";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      seccion: [],
      descriptionSeccion: "",
      descripcionGenero: "",
      genre: [],
    };
  },

  computed: {
    getServices: function () {
      let serv;
      let seccion;
      // Obtenemos las keys del Json
      let serviceKeys = Object.keys(servicios.services);
      //Establecemos el valor de nuestras variables
      console.log(this.$route.params.miau);

      let target = serviceKeys.some(function (key) {
        if (servicios.services[key].slug === "peliculas") {
          seccion = servicios.services[key];
          return seccion;
        }
      });

      // si se ha encontrado un valor válido con el criterio
      // filtramos los géneros
      if (target) {
        let genreKeys = Object.keys(seccion.genres);
        genreKeys.some(function (genreKey) {
          let currentGenre = this.$route.params.miau;
          console.log(currentGenre);
          if (currentGenre === seccion.genres[genreKey].slug) {
            serv = seccion.genres[genreKey];
            return serv;
          }
        });
      }
      console.log("llegué aquí");
      return serv;
    },
  },
  getValue() {},
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Recibo estos errores en consola: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siguiendo el tutorial de Vue de School.io, intenté hacer la siguiente propiedad computada

```
 getGenre: function () {
      return this.$route.params.miau;
    },
```

```
 // si se ha encontrado un valor válido con el criterio
      // filtramos los géneros
      if (target) {
        let genreKeys = Object.keys(seccion.genres);
        genreKeys.some(function (genreKey) {
          if (this.getGenre === seccion.genres[genreKey].slug) {
            serv = seccion.genres[genreKey];
            return serv;
          }
        });
      }
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta o posteala en el sitio en inglés. Esto es stackoverflow en español.

Comment: Añadida versión resumida en español para cumplir las normas del foro, mis disculpas.

Comment: Luis, gracias por tu rápida respuesta, pero la versión en inglés de tu pregunta no tiene por qué existir. Son dos sitios diferentes https://stackoverflow.com/ y https://es.stackoverflow.com/. Si gustas coloca también tu pregunta en la versión en inglés, pero las preguntas deben ser completas en inglés  o completas en español dependiendo del sitio. No tiene sentido dos enunciados.

Comment: Ya edité tu pregunta. Ahora, lo siguiente. Probaste crear la variable currentGenre dentro del objeto que retorna ``data()`` en lugar de crearla dentro de la funcion computada con ``let``? de la siguiente manera ``currentGenre: this.$route.params.miau``. Luego en lugar de hacer ``if (currentGenre === seccion.genres[genreKey].slug)`` haces ``if (this.currentGenre === seccion.genres[genreKey].slug)``

Comment: Buenas noches Agustín, gracias por tu respuesta y edición,  y lamento las molestias. He probado lo que me dices:

 `data() {
    return {
      seccion: [],
      descriptionSeccion: "",
      descripcionGenero: "",
      genre: [],
      currentGenre: this.$route.params.miau,
    };`
con: 
` if (this.currentGenre === seccion.genres[genreKey].slug) {
            serv = seccion.genres[genreKey];
            return serv;
          }`
Pero no ha habido éxito: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'currentGenre')**

Comment: perdon @LuisBauer si no usas el arroba con mi nombre no me llega la notificación de la respuesta. Mmm la verdad que no sé como ayudarte, si queres hacer una copia en algun servicio de git del proyecto, con gusto lo clono, lo corro y lo reviso. Necesitaría meter console.log por todos lados jaja

Comment: Otra cosa, en el título dice que estás usando VUE 3 pero en el código estás usando la funcion ``data()`` que corresponde a VUE 2 (si bien se puede usar en vue 3). En vue 3 podrias usar la funcion setup, importas useRoute, lo declaras en una constante reactiva (``const route = useRoute()``), y haces route.value.params si mal no recuerdo. Puede que haya algun inconvieniente entre la ``Options API``, la ``Composition API``, y la palabra this. Pero por eso te digo, si subis eso a algun repo y me pasas el link lo reviso completo.

Comment: has anadido el router a tu aplicacion Vue ? hay que hacerlo en el main.js

Comment: Buenos días Agustín, te dejo el link de un repositorio de Git con la carpeta del proyecto: [https://github.com/Nodgar/Projects] . Voy a investigar no obstante lo que me comentas ahora en cuanto tenga un segundo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Buenas Adri, si el contenido de mi main.js desplegado con CLI incluye el router:
`import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");`

Comment: Disculpa, que anadaba hasta arriba con el curro @AgustinG. y se me paso por alto lo de la arroba, te he dejado en uno de los comenatrios de arriba un link al proyecto subido en Git Hub, espero te sirva, muchsímas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @LuisBauer hay varios errores, primero en el route no tenes ningun componente definido para la ruta "/" entonces recibis un error al entrar. En cuanto al componente DescripcionPelicula, para poder atrapar el parametro que viene por la ruta, primero defini en la funcion data un ``currentGenre: null``, y luego fuera del data hice ``created(){ this.currentGenre = this.$route.params.miau } ``.
Luego en la funcion computada ``getServices``, declaro una variable al principio ``let gen = this.currentGenre;`` y en el segundo ``if`` hago   ``if (gen === seccion.genres[genreKey].slug)``

Comment: @LuisBauer Ahora bien, este cambio que hice solo va a funcionar cuando escribas bien la ruta, por ejemplo ``http://localhost:8080/peliculas/terror``, si escribis cualquier slug que no puedas encontrar va a arrojar un error. Simplemente porque no hay ``else`` en los ``if``, deberias redirigir o mostrar algún error en los casos que no exista el genero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así queda DescripcionPelicula.vue, primero deshabilité Eslint porque me molestaba. Cree la variable `currentGenre` como null y la cargué con el valor de `this.$route.params.miau` en el hook `created`.

Luego dentro de la función computada, hay un error con `this` que no logro interpretar, por lo cual no permite leer `this.currentGenre` en el `if` anidado, entonces si a la variable `this.currentGenre` la guardo dentro de una variable local a la funcion computada, anda sin problemas.
Finalmente hacemos `if (gen === seccion.genres[genreKey].slug)`.

De esta manera, siempre que escribas un genero correcto (ejemplo 'terror') va a andar bien. Cuando escribas un genero que no encuentre dentro de tu array va a arrojar error, porque no estás manejando errores en esos `if`.

Ejemplo:

> http://localhost:8080/peliculas/terror anda perfecto

> http://localhost:8080/peliculas/asd arroja errores por consola, porque el `slug` es indefinido.

```
<script>
// primero deshabilité Eslint porque me molestaba
/* eslint-disable */
import servicios from "../../data.json";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      seccion: [],
      descriptionSeccion: "",
      descripcionGenero: "",
      genre: [],
      currentGenre: null, // Creo la variable "currentGenre" como null
    };
  },

  created(){
    // la cargo en el hook ``created``.
    this.currentGenre = this.$route.params.miau;
  },
  computed: {
    getServices: function () {
      let serv;
      let seccion;
      // Guardo el genero en una variable local al scope de la funcion
      let gen = this.currentGenre;
      let serviceKeys = Object.keys(servicios.services);

      let target = serviceKeys.some(function (key) {
        if (servicios.services[key].slug === "peliculas") {
          seccion = servicios.services[key];
          return seccion;
        }
      });

      if (target) {
        let genreKeys = Object.keys(seccion.genres);
        genreKeys.some(function (genreKey) {
          // Aca hago uso de la variable local "gen"
          if (gen === seccion.genres[genreKey].slug) {
            serv = seccion.genres[genreKey];
            return serv;
          }
        });
      }
      console.log("llegué aquí");
      return serv;
    },
  },
  getValue() {},
};
</script>
```

Comment: Perfecto, infinitas gracias, la solución funciona correctamente. Yo incialmente había intentado usar el hook de mounted pero sin éxito. Con created funciona a la perfección

Answer (score 1):

para cualquiera que lee este Post, desde Vue Schools.IO se ha dado otra respuesta que soluciona el problema:

en la llamada a:

```
genreKeys.some(function (genreKey) {
      if (this.$route.params.miau === seccion.genres[genreKey].slug) {
        serv = seccion.genres[genreKey];
        return serv;
      }
    });
```

Cambiando la función some a una arrow function de la siguiente manera:

```
genreKeys.some((genreKey) => {
      if (this.$route.params.miau === seccion.genres[genreKey].slug) {
        serv = seccion.genres[genreKey];
        return serv;
      }
    });
```

Permite que el this.$routes encuentre el contexto de forma correcta, y por lo tanto retornando el valor adecuado, esto adicionalmente explica por que el valor del parametro se podía imprimir fuera en un console.log, pero no funcionaba dentro de este bloque de código.